# Convert PHP SOAP call to Postman

Tags: php, xml, soap, postman

I am trying to make a SOAP call using POSTMAN that will duplicate a call I'm making with a PHP code for testing purposes, but I am getting a "Bad request" error message, so I assume my conversion is incorrect.
The PHP code is:

```
//Create xml string
                $xml=new DomDocument();
                $xml->createCDATASection('![CDATA[]]');
                $xml->encoding = 'utf-8';
                $xml->xmlVersion = '1.0';
                $xml->formatOutput = true;
                $xsd=$xml->createElement("xsd:schema");
                $xml->appendChild($xsd);
                $xsdattr=new DOMAttr("xmlns:xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                $xsd->setAttributeNode($xsdattr);
                $ZHT=$xml->createElement("ZHT",str_replace(" ","",$username));
                $xsd->appendChild($ZHT);
                $PASSWORD=$xml->createElement("PASSWORD",str_replace(" ","",$pwd));
                $xsd->appendChild($PASSWORD);
                $SNL=$xml->createElement("SNL",$date);
                $xsd->appendChild($SNL);
                $USERNAME=$xml->createElement("USERNAME","");
                $xsd->appendChild($USERNAME);
                $RETHASIMA=$xml->createElement("RETHASIMA","1");
                $xsd->appendChild($RETHASIMA);
                $LANG=$xml->createElement("LANG","");
                $xsd->appendChild($LANG);
                $ROLE=$xml->createElement("ROLE",$role);
                $xsd->appendChild($ROLE);
                $xmlstring=$xml->saveXML();
                
                //Set SOAP request
                    $baseURL=$url;
                    $arrContextOptions=array("ssl"=>array( "verify_peer"=>false, "verify_peer_name"=>false,'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT));
               
                    $options = array(
                        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
                        'trace'      => true,
                        'exceptions' => true,                // disable exceptions
                        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
                    );
                    
                    $client  = new SoapClient($baseURL."?wsdl", $options); 
                    
                    $p=array(
                        "P_RequestParams" => array (
                                                                "RequestID"=>"48",
                                                                "InputData"=>$xmlstring
                                                            ) ,
                        "Authenticator" =>  array (
                                                            "Password"=>$authpass,
                                                            "UserName"=>$authuser
                                                        ),
                    );
                    
                    //SOAP call and response
                    $response=$client->ProcessRequestJSON($p);
```

And This is the body I created in POSTMAN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessRequestJSON xmlns="****">
      <P_RequestParams>
        <RequestID>48</RequestID>
        <InputData>
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                <schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <PARAMS>
                        <ZHT>****</ZHT>
                        <PASSWORD>****</PASSWORD>
                        <SNL>***</SNL>
                        <USERNAME></USERNAME>
                        <RETHASIMA>1</RETHASIMA>
                        <LANG></LANG>
                        <ROLE>1</ROLE>
                    </PARAMS>
                </schema>
        </InputData>
      </P_RequestParams>
      <Authenticator>
        <UserName>****</UserName>
        <Password>****</Password>
      </Authenticator>
    </ProcessRequestJSON>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm not sure how to set certain things on POSTMAN.
For example, the following line:

```
$xsdattr=new DOMAttr("xmlns:xsd","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

How do I set a DOMAttr in POSTMAN?
Or the options?

I set up the headers for XML:
Content-Type: text/xml
SOAPAction: "****/ProcessRequestJSON"
Body: Raw (XML)

I tried putting the inner XML (inside the  tag) in "" to indicate a string, but that didn't work either.

The PHP code works correctly, the SOAP call is successful and returns a correct response.
The POSTMAN request returns a "Bad Request" error message.

Comment: As use the trace mode with SoapClient, you can get the last request https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php to obtain the XML boilerplate which you then could perhaps just put into postman (never did SOAP with Postman, but your question looks like you want to ensure the XML is correctly ported, therefore why not copy it over?)